# Android Simulator Date/Time is set to previous day

Tags: android

Running Android Studio on a Mac, with x86 images (Android 6.0 with Google APIs) for the simulator.   I have tried to have the date/time for the simulator update automatically, and I have set it manually, but each time I start the simulator it's a day behind.   Any suggestions on how to correct what seems to be a default simulator behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In my simulator i have this settings, and it's working fine even if restarted.

I had to setup the timezone manually because i'm under proxy and if left automatic the timezone results in a couple of hours behind the real ones.

[image]

PS: i'm using Android Studio 2.3.1 with Android Emulator 26.0.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Thanks, manually setting the time zone with the automatic turned on seemed to fix the issue.  I'm also behind a proxy.

Comment: If this solved your problem you can accept the answer ;)